# Display message with while loop if a variable goes lower than zero in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm sorry if I'm being stupid. I am just starting to learn Javascript and am messing around with loops.
I'm currently messing about with this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">---</button>

<p id="hpcount"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
var health = 30;    
document.getElementById("hpcount").innerHTML = health;

while (health < 0){
    health = 0;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Game over";
    break;
}

function myFunction() {
    if (health>0){
        health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
        document.getElementById("hpcount").innerHTML = health;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that the button subtracts a random integer 1-10 from the variable "health" as long as health is larger than 0. Then if it goes lower than that, display the "game over" message and reset health to 0.
However, while the button stops working once health>0, the message just wont appear, and I just can't figure out why no matter how many times I look over the syntax and structure...
Am I being stupid and missing something obvious?

Comment: `while` is executed when the condition can be evaluated to `true`. In your case the loop is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while (health < 0){
    health = 0;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Game over";
    break;
}

function myFunction() {
    if (health>0){
        health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
        document.getElementById("hpcount").innerHTML = health;
    }
}
```

To this:

```
function myFunction() {
    // if health is above 0, game is still active
    if (health>0){
        // generate a new health value
        health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;

        // check if the game should end
        if (health <= 0) {
            health = 0;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Game over";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("hpcount").innerHTML = health;
        }
    }
}
```

While you are learning Javascript, consider getting familiar with [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which simplifies the use of javascript and dealing with cross-browser/device compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you actually want to write a loop using a named function and *setTimeout*

```
var health = 30, // initial health
    logbox = document.getElementById("demo2");

function checkHealth() {
    if (health <= 0) { // dead
        logbox.innerHTML = "Game over";
    } else { // alive
        logbox.innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (true) // set some condition so this doesn't go on forever?
        window.setTimeout(checkHealth, 500); // repeat every 500ms
}

checkHealth(); // start it running
```

Now when you have some change happen to `health`, it will be *"monitored"*, but if lots of changes happen under (in this case) *500 ms*, the code will only react to how it has ended up after the time has passed

---

An alternative way is to invoke a *callback* whenever a function modifies `health`, which does this check. This means you only check as it's needed, but if you have lots of changes happen in under 1 ms (think thousands or more for a PC) you may end up freezing up the browser until it's completed the functions. You also need to make sure you don't set up an infinite loop.

In this style, you would not modify `health` directly, but write some *API*, e.g.

```
var health = 30, // initial health
    logbox = document.getElementById("demo2");

function checkHealth() {
    // take real care if you want to call `setHealth` or `addHealth` here
    // otherwise you may end up with an infinite loop
    if (health <= 0) { // dead
        logbox.innerHTML = "Game over";
    } else { // alive
        logbox.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function setHealth(x) {
    health = x;
    checkHealth();
}

function getHealth() {
    return health;
}

// or perhaps even
function addHealth(x) {
    health += x;
    checkHealth();
}
```

Now to modify health,

```
var x = getHealth(); // get current
setHealth(x - 3); // make change
// or
addHealth(-3);
```

Comment: This is a reasonable alternative to the technique I offered up, though in this specific case probably unnecessary. I think you should avoid using the phrase "monitored" here as it usually implies an observer-style pattern which this is definitely not, but otherwise yes, this is an important technique to understand in learning javascript.

Comment: I used quotes and further explained what I meant, but if you can think of a word which better describes what is happening than _"monitored"_ I'd be happy to edit it

Comment: Maybe "checked" would be a better word? Don't get me wrong, I'm one of the +1s for the answer, I just wonder if we can make that one part clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a while loop here at all. There is nothing to loop, you're doing one thing that's triggered by a click.

I took the liberty of rewriting your code to use [unobtrusive javascript techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), [not expose globals](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/), and be a bit clearer.

[Here it is working](http://jsbin.com/zuheh/2/edit?html,js,output)

```
(function() {

var health = 30, 
    hpCountEl = document.getElementById("hpcount")
   ;    
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', subtractHealth);
showHealth();

function showHealth() {
  hpCountEl.textContent = health;  
  if(health === 0)
    document.getElementById('demo2').textContent = "Game Over"
}
function subtractHealth() {
    if (health>0)
        health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
    if(health <= 0)
      health = 0;
    showHealth()
}

})();
```

Something else to note - you typically do not want to put strings such as "Game Over" into javascript as it can be difficult to localize if you want to offer multiple language support. Instead you should prefer having a hidden element containing that text on the page, and simply make it visible when you need it.

Comment: Whilst I like _unobtrusive JavaScript_ a **lot**, I think you may be using too many new concepts at once for someone `just starting to learn`

Comment: @PaulS. The selector cache might be a bit much, but I disagree about not introducing IIFEs and unobtrusive JS to beginners. Global state is such a huge cause of bugs, and such a weird javascript feature that I've found it's better to start with these features as a black box and let students get into how and why they work later on when they get curious. Otherwise people spend a lot of time chasing down heisenbugs (and more importantly - not learning) that really could have been avoided if we guided them into the pit of success in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is being called once on initialization, evaluating to false, not being called and then never being called again.

You should move it inside myFunction as a normal if check.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a variable scope problem . Try passing health as a parameter to your function .

```
function myFunction(health) {
    if (health>0){
        health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
        document.getElementById("hpcount").innerHTML = health;
    }
```

Comment: The variable `health` is in the global namespace so it will be accessible within the `myFunction()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you require a while loop, a simple if and else if check would do in this situation. Since you are only checking to see what the variable health is on click you would only need to check it once per click. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLv2x5y5/) of how I would do this.

```
  var health = 30;    
    document.getElementById("hpcount").innerHTML = health;

  function myFunction() {
     if(health <= 0) {
       health = 0;
       document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Game over";
     }
     else if (health>0){
       health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
       document.getElementById("hpcount").innerHTML = health;
     }
   }
```

Comment: FYI. This is not quite correct. The game should end when health drops below zero, so the value of health should be checked immediately after a new value is generated. The way this function is presently coded, the game won't end until after the user clicks the button again even if the health value has already dropped below zero in the prior click.